# React-Native : ES6 or ES5 classes?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What are the benefits of using ES6 classes over ES5 classes?

Comment: ES6 has classes, ES5 doesn't. I think the benefit is apparent immediately :)

Comment: Their syntax is more comfortable, and they're future-compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use ES6 classes. ES5 doesn't have a class definition compared to ES6.

One thing to realize is that the ES6 code you write is `transpiled` to ES5 by the packager anyway.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 as it's pretty cool for example in ES5

```
function times2(value) { return value * 2; }
```

same thing in ES6

```
value => value * 2
```

using fat arrow function.